# C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, interop

I'm creating an Excel worksheet dynamically via C#.  I have a requirement that all active cells within a specific column has a dropdown with data that I provide.

I can get it working on a single cell as such:

```
        Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)activeSheet.Cells[Type.Missing, 4];
        Excel.DropDowns dropDowns;
        Excel.DropDown dropDown;
        dropDowns = ((Excel.DropDowns)(activeSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
        dropDown = dropDowns.Add((double)range.Left, (double)range.Top, (double)range.Width, (double)range.Height, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            dropDown.AddItem(i.ToString());
        }
```

However, I can't seem to get it to appear only in active cells for a specific column.  Any ideas?

Thanks.